# Is there a way to know the SCM url used in a Jenkins job programmatically?

Tags: maven-2, jenkins

I'm currently creating a custom [Maven enforcer rule](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/index.html), and for its purpose, I need to know the URL of the SCM (Subversion, Git...) used for the given job, i.e. where the sources were just checkouted by the Jenkins job.
Is there a way to get that information?

I had a look on the parameters [set in system environment by Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project), but none of them give me the full SCM url used by the job. Also, the API (i.e. `http://jenkins-server/job/my-job/api/xml`) does not contain this information.

I know that there is a `<scm><connection>` tag in the `pom.xml`, but this information may not be reliable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These values are set by the SCM implementation. To find out which environment variables actually exist in your build, you can use the *EnvInject* plugin.

For Subversion, you can use the environment variable `SVN_URL` (if it's one URL only), or `SVN_URL_n`, `n` being a number (if it's multiple URLs) as described [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Plugin#SubversionPlugin-SubversionRevisionandURLinformationasEnvironmentVariables).

You could also use the *System Groovy* build step in the *Groovy* plugin to access the Jenkins object tree directly and e.g. write this information to a file. Note that accessing internals in prone to breaking in updates, and prone to breaking Jenkins if you're not careful.